# Is it secure to Store value in var for PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wonder if it secure to store value for a prepared query like that :

```
$notGood = 'yes';
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id_user, name_user, tel_user, a_valid_user FROM user WHERE a_valid_user = ?');
$req->execute([$notGood];
```

I do not know if it's the right way to do when you know in advance the value.
Thanks for your advices

Comment: Why won't bind a param?

Comment: I do not really have a good level, and I am afraid of losing time with casting errors during dev

Comment: It would be the right way?

Comment: You should use $req->bindParam(':a_valid_user', $notGood, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();

Comment: it would be the right way? while being careful with good cast

Comment: Yes use the right way as I wrotr.

Comment: just curious, as long as it is prepared, the security at this level is the same for both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as your variable is represented by a placeholder (`?`) in the query, it is safe.

In case you are curious whether it is secure or not to send a variable into execute, it's just a *syntax sugar* for `bindValue()`, which makes PDO extremely convenient in use. So I recommend to use it whenever possible.

Comment: Ty, it was my question